# Htaccess Rewrite Minimum occurrence of a certain character REGEX

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]{29,}+).php?$ _content.php?_p1=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Instead of the parameter being a minimum of 29, Is there a way we can replace this to have the condition where it matches those with the minimum occurrence of 3 hyphens (-)?

'-' minimum 3 per url...
?

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to replace your statement that checks for 29 characters with this:

```
(?=-)(-\w*){3,}
```

Positive lookahead will start by finding the first occurrence of your hyphen, then will match 3+ hyphens followed by word characters. The reason for the positive lookahead is to bypass the `.` in `.com`, `.net`, etc, as well as the forward slashes you may see in folders.

Working with 3+ hyphens: **[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sESeBw/1)**
Broken Without 3+ hyphens: **[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sESeBw/2)**

Comment: RewriteRule ^(?=-)(-\w*){3,}.php?$ _content.php?_p1=$1 [QSA,L]   like this?

Comment: Are you trying to use an actual period before php? Because if so, you need to escape that `\.php`. Actually, you really need to escape much more than that... Is the rest of that line all literal values?

Comment: nope.. its a rewrite, so the param needs to be the slug of the urll.... this works, as you answered already.. ^([a-z0-9-]([a-z0-9-]+)(?=-)(-\w*){3,}+).php?$ _content.php?_p1=$1

Comment: ^(([a-z0-9-]+)(?=-)(-\w*){3,}+).php?$ _content.php?_p1=$1

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z0-9-]{29})(\.php)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(([^-]*)\-){3,29}(\.php)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$    _content.php?_p1=$1 [L]
```

The code will match any URI contains `[a-z0-9-]` with `29` length and with or without `.php` and have at least `3` hyphens.